# Longest subset of numbers in Scheme

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket

I'm new to learning scheme so I have a few questions.
So I am writing a program that looks within a given list and returns the longest subset of identical numbers.

```
i.e (longestsubset '(1 2 3 3 4 5))
> ( 3 3 )
```

I am currently having issues with the recursive part of the problem. When I find two numbers that are equal I am adding them to a list to return them but I don't know how to do that after the first two elements or compared to longer subsets.

```
i.e  (longestsubset '(1 1 1 2 3 3 4 5))
    > ( 1 1 1 )
```

Right now I have:

```
(define (longestsubset L)
  (cond
    ((null? L) nil)
    ((null? (cdr L)) nil)
    ((equal? (car L) (cadr L)) (list(car L) (cadr L)))
    (else (longestsubset (cdr L)))))
```

I was thinking of having something like 
`((equal? (car L) (cadr L)) (list(car L) (longestsubset (cdr L)))` but it doesn't seem to work.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You're never comparing the lengths of different subsets.

Comment: @Barmar how could I do that?

Comment: You need to pass the current longest subset in the recursive call. And the recursive call needs to keep appending the current element to the current subset.

Comment: This is essentially an exact duplicate of [Longest chain of element in lisp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60855097/longest-chain-of-element-in-lisp), which already has an answer.

Comment: You can read HTDP if you want understand basic Racket knowledge.